# Allow empty html tags in ckeditor

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using ckeditor 3.1 in an MVC application. If an html tag is empty then it places `&nbsp;` in it.
i want to allow div tag as empty(`<div></div>`), and no   to be get inserted(`<div>&nbsp;</div>`) . I have also used the latest code for ckeditor(3.3.1) but the same probelm persist.
Do we have to make some manual change in any particular file.

Please provide me the solution to allow empty tags using ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable **AutoParagraph** in the **AutoFormat** section in `/settings/filters`.

If this seems to no longer work, try [this](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16915) instead.

Comment: In which file the AutoFormat section is defined as I make the search with AutoFormat in the code but didn't get it.

Comment: It seems it is different for .NET (or it is the new version), but that property exists in drupal version.
I have found a general solution on their forum (edited the answer).

Comment: I am new to it.I am not understanding where we have to place the code that is mentioned on the ckeditor forum

Comment: It is a initialization code so place it to some Init method or to the config.js file (after the configuration has been initialized).